# Double Boot problem - Can't remove Minimal Bash

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub, boot-loader

I'm quite lost here, but I would say this is a problem where the boot manager is not installed in the right place. This started when I re-installed ubuntu after it crashed and couldn't re boot it.

My HP Laptop had a Windows, and then ubuntu, and now the re-install of ubuntu.

I've tried many "Minimal bash fix" solutions around, which basically tell me to use a live USB to boot and do a `boot-repair` and `grub-install` after re-boot. I think I've end up installing another grub in another partition.

**Situation**

When powering on, I've

1. the minimal bash screen, which I can exit
   [image: 1st Screen]
2. then a 2nd screen which ask me where to boot (I use the 3rd one)
   [image: 2nd Screen]
3. a 3rd GRUB screen, which sends me to boot my ubuntu
   [image: 3rd Screen]

## Here some Info

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 937701375 936648706 446,6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *    1052672 937701375 936648704 446,6G 83 Linux
```

(W95 ???)

- **sda1:** has `EFI/BOOT` and `EFI/ubuntu`
- **sda5:** has an empty `boot/efi/` and a filled `boot/grub/`

not sure if this is important.

Any help sorting this out will be much appreciated, I'd like to return to the purple boot mgr, or even no boot manager at all.

**EDIT**: Adding Boot-repair pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XjRxJCqJNm/

Comment: You must have mixed BIOS/MBR and UEFI/gpt configurations. You show an ESP - efi system partition but also an extended partition which is only with MBR. Your UEFI/BIOS is probably set to boot in BIOS mode, finds an old grub in MBR and fails. Then it reboots, first menu you show is your UEFI boot menu and then grub menu from UEFI install. To confirm: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks @oldfred here's the link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XjRxJCqJNm/

Comment: You show a newer UEFI system. But have Ubuntu installed in both old BIOS and newer UEFI boot modes, but old MBR(msdos) partitioning. No evidence of Windows anywhere? You show boot flag on sda5, but for UEFI boot it must be on ESP - efi system partiiton which is the FAT32 one, your sda1. You have grub installed in three places, MBR for BIOS boot, ESP for UEFI boot and in the FAT32 partition boot sector which may corrupt the FAT32. Never install grub to a partition. And with UEFI, you really should use gpt partitioning. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs or repairs.

Comment: Thanks again, however, I don't really know how to continue at this point.. I fear doing more harm. Any suggestions on how to tidy all this up and get back to a "normal" state? 
Sorry, I'm not very experienced at this level.

Comment: Would it be safe for me to remove sda1 and sda2 in order to keep sda5 booting process?

Comment: It you remove sda2, you also remove sda5 as sda2 is an extended partition which is the container for all your logical partitions currently just sda5. You can just run Boot-Repair to reinstall grub to MBR and make sure UEFI set set to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. But since hardware newer UEFI, better to do full backup, convert drive to gpt which will erase it and reinstall in UEFI boot mode. Backup should include /home, list of installed apps and perhaps some other folders if you edited system config or added server type software.